# How to reserve space for responsive img (stop blocks jumping down)

Tags: html, css

How to solve a problem of jumping down blocks after image load if image should be responsive?

[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/wild-thunder-2btzy?file=/src/App.js).

Info:

- Image should shrink on window resize
- Image max-width is it's own width
- We don't know image size
- JS can be used

Idea:

If it's not possible without any image size data, then can it be done only with image aspect ratio?

If you know image aspect ratio, you can calculate block height and put responsive image inside with some unused space (at least unused space will be not big on small window size).

Image loading:
[image]

Image loaded:
[image]

Html:

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

const img =
  "https://s3.amazonaws.com/images.seroundtable.com/google-css-images-1515761601.jpg";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="app">
      <img alt="" src={img + `?${Date.now()}`} className="img" />
      <h1>I always jump down :(</h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```

CSS:

```
.app {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
h1 {
  background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: In this situation I would usually take a rough guess at the size, then animate the size-change to it's true size once it's loaded (Since you can't prevent a height change if you don't know the end height, and it's smoother than something popping in)

Comment: @DBS even with slow animation i'm not sure it's will be pleasant when block will go down. What about aspect ration idea?

Comment: If you know the aspect ratio in advance, you can calculate the height from the displayed width. But I assume you don't know that until the image has loaded, which leaves the same problem with the before/after load styling. If you do know the aspect ratio, then a little JS maths can get you the height needed.

Comment: @DBS i have recommended aspect ratio for banner images that user upload, so i may say that i know it. Added an example based on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AS @DBS sad, it seems that only solution is to wrap image in div block with calculated height based on window.width and aspect ratio (in my case i know it). If there is any better solutions, don't hesitate to answer.

Sandbox [solution example](https://codesandbox.io/s/nice-dawn-pzj73?file=/src/App.js).

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import styled from "styled-components";

const aspectRatio = [1, 5];

const img =
  "https://s3.amazonaws.com/images.seroundtable.com/google-css-images-1515761601.jpg";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="app">
      <StyledDiv>
        <img alt="" src={img + `?${Date.now()}`} className="img" />
      </StyledDiv>

      <h1>I always jump down :(</h1>
    </div>
  );
}

const StyledDiv = styled.div`
  height: calc(100vw / ${aspectRatio[1]});
  overflow-y: hidden;
`;
```

Answer (score 0):

As you've already determined, even when knowing the aspect ratio, we still have the problem of not knowing the width of the image, making the aspect ratio useless if we are to conform to your requirement `Image max-width is it's own width`.

What would work is a build time solution (if you know your image urls at build time). There are plenty of server side rendering options for react apps and I will not elaborate on them.

Instead there's a super rudimentary DIY approach.

1. Create a **Node** script to run on your server. It will build JSON file with image dimensions. Let's call it "buildImageDimensionData.js". It will output a JSON file `imageDimensions.json`.

```
var probe = require("probe-image-size"); // For getting image dimensions without downloading full image
const fs = require("fs"); // For writing our image dimensions to file

// Supply the image urls by hand, or build a webpack script to extract them etc...
const imageUrls = [
  `http://localhost:5000/image1.jpg`,
  `http://localhost:5000/image2.jpg`,
];

async function getImageDimensionsByUrl(urlList) {
  const probePromises = urlList.map(async (imageUrl) => await probe(imageUrl));
  let probedImagesData = [];

  try {
    probedImagesData = await Promise.all(probePromises);
  } catch (error) {
    // We are programming gods and there will be no error.
  }

  return probedImagesData.reduce((accumulator, imageData) => {
    accumulator[imageData.url] = [imageData.width, imageData.height];
    return accumulator;
  }, {});
}

getImageDimensionsByUrl(imageUrls).then((dimensions) =>
  fs.writeFileSync("imageDimensions.json", JSON.stringify(dimensions))
);
```

2. Run the script before build. For example, if you're using Create React App, in package.json:

```
    ...
    "start": "buildImageDimensionData && react-scripts start",
    "build": "buildImageDimensionData && react-scripts build",
    ...
```

3. In your react image component, `import imageDimensions.json` and use the data to set dimensions for image wrapper based on url of the image.

Note this is more for demonstraing how it could work and there will definitely be packages for doing this better.

---

Another, albeit poor option is of course just waiting for the images to load before rendering your other content so no jumps occur.

Answer (score -2):

To ignore the jump down, you have to set margin of the next sibling to 0,

```html
.app {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
.app :nth-child(2) {
margin:0px
}
```

Comment: h1 is just example of some content, there can be any block with any data.

Comment: you just need to ignore margin whatever the block you use

Comment: please let me know your exact problem,
you need to delete the jump between your loaded image and the element after?

Comment: @ZiiMakc please check the generic solution that I have post,
this solution will get the next cibling of your image and reset its margin to 0px,
it should work for you

Comment: please open sandbox and check it yourself, it doesn't work.

Comment: now it works,
https://codesandbox.io/s/wild-hooks-6hp4b?file=/src/styles.css,
it is because your image is wrapped within a styleddiv